# Reading an excel file in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading an excel file into pandas, but I am getting the following:

```
Out[8]:
0        \tFLOOD LIGHTS\t
1        \tFLOOD LIGHTS\t
2        \tPAR 38 LIGHT\t
3                \tMILO\t
4    \tQ-12251-DO1 MILO\t
```

I do not want the "\t" in my data.  Here is my pandas read command:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_ex('/home/Desktop/sample.xlsx')
```

Comment: What is the output you would like to see?  What's wrong with what you have currently?

Comment: I don't think it's a pandas issue. You actually have those tab characters in the Excel file probably.

Comment: I want these  '\t' to be dropped, is it any encoding issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have trailing tabs in your data.

So need [`strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) for remove it:

```
data['col'] = data['col'].str.strip()
```

If all columns:

```
data = data.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip())

#then convert possible numeric columns
data['num_col'] = data['num_col'].astype(int)
```

---

Or if need remove `\t` strings use [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) with `^` for start of string and `$` for end:

```
data = data['col'].replace(['^\t', '\t$'], '', regex=True)
```

Comment: It was really helpful. Thanks